# How to link ESP8266 with a C# application written in Xamarin form?

Tags: c#, xamarin, esp8266

I have a [C# application](https://gifyu.com/image/SLu1A) written in Xamarin form, and there is a device called a "Wind Box". This is a conventional smoke trap, necessary for filtering toxic substances formed during soldering. There is a cooler in it, it is regulated by a transistor, the transistor regulates the ESP. As a result, the application must adjust the power of the cooler.
I absolutely do not understand how to link a C# application and an ESP8266 that will regulate all this. I am more interested in what needs to be written to the application so that it manages the ESP8266.
Can you recommend any sources on this topic. How to link ESP8266 and a C# application written in xamarin form.

[My ESP8266](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwvjT.png)

Comment: If you control the ESP8266, expose some kind of API that the phone App can talk to. This could be through BLE, HTTP or some other means.

Comment: You could take a look at the `Iot.Device.Bindings` package. It contains a binding (driver) for Arduino/Firmata, which is a special firmware you would load on your ESP so that it can be controlled from the PC. The exact settings required will depend on how the ESP is connected to the PC (serial, Wifi or otherwise).

Comment: Have you looked at all the other questions in the [ESP8266](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esp8266) tag?